# Compiling Python to C using Cython

Tags: python, c, linux, gcc, cython

I'm trying to compile `python` source code foo.py to C using [`cython`](http://cython.org/).

In `foo.py`:

```
print "Hello World"
```

The command I'm running is `cython foo.py`.

The problem is that when compiling foo.c using [`gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/), I get the error:

`undefined reference to 'main'`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

when converting the code from python to c (using Cython) it converts it to c code which can be compiled into a shared object.
in order to make it executable, you should add "--embed" to cython conversion command. this flag adds the 'main' function you need, so you could compile the c code into executable file.
please notice you'll need the python `.so` runtime libraries in order to run the exec.

Comment: See [Cython GitHub Wiki: Embedding Cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EmbeddingCython).

Answer (score 9):

Read the Cython documentation. This will also (hopefully) teach you what Cython is and what it isn't. Cython is for creating python extensions (not a general-purpose Python-to-C-compiler), which are shared objects/dlls. Dynamically loaded libraries don't have a `main` function like standalone programs, but compilers assume that they are ultimately linking an executable. You have to tell them otherwise via flags (`-shared` methinks, but again, refer to the Cython documentation) - or even better, don't compile yourself, use a `setup.py` for this (yet again, read the Cython documentation).

Comment: for me this answer resulted in compilation of a working extension. answer of RoeeK resolved the linking problem, but after Python failed to import with error `ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function`. thank you really much, I think would be nicer to write it with less lecturing style without assuming stupidity as the 3 rtfm suggests.

Comment: This answer would be perfect if it included a link to the [Cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the [Cython FAQ](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-run-doctests-in-cython-code-pyx-files).

Comment: Not a very helpful answer. It's basically a RTFM but wrong as proven by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to use distutils to compile the cython-generated file. This also gives you all the  include directories you need in a portable way.